# Image validation extension validation only if not empty issue

Tags: php, validation, cakephp

im using a validation rule for image file in cakephp that i want to validate image extension  only if not empty.
the problem is that  cakephp is validating the extension if i don't give an image so it gives the validation error 'Only images files'
here's my validation rule that i use to validate an image

```
image' => array(
            'notEmpty' => array(
                //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
                'allowEmpty' => true,
                'required' => false,
                //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
                //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
            ),
            'extension' => array(
                'rule' => array('extension', array('png','jpg','jpeg')),
                'message' => 'Only images files',
            ),
```

i use this plugin for image upload https://github.com/josegonzalez/cakephp-upload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `notEmpty` rule doesn't appear to do anything as you haven't specified a rule so can probably be removed.

You need to add the `'allowEmpty' => true` to the `extension` rule to tell Cake to ignore the rule if the field is empty:-

```
public $validate = array(
    'image' => array(
        'extension' => array(
            'rule' => array('extension', array('png','jpg','jpeg')),
            'message' => 'Only images files',
            'allowEmpty' => true
        )
    )
);
```

**Update**

The CakePHP Upload plugin has its [own extension validation rule](https://cakephp-upload.readthedocs.org/en/latest/validation.html#isvalidextension), `isValidExtension`, that you can use:-

```
public $validate = array(
    'image' => array(
        'extension' => array(
            'rule' => array(
                'isValidExtension', 
                array('png','jpg','jpeg'), 
                false
            ),
            'message' => 'Only images files'
        )
    )
);
```

Passing `false` as the third parameter of the rule (as above) ensures that the rule is only checked when a file is uploaded.

Comment: it didn't work, i've tried it already, i don't know what's causing this validation error even with allowempty set to true

Comment: Are you absolutely sure `image` is coming through as empty? Have you tried debugging the `extension` validation rule itself to see what it is failing on?

Comment: thank you for pointing that out, after searching in the plugin documentation i've found a custom validation for the plugin, so i think it gives an empty string so that's why i get the validation error , here's the link https://cakephp-upload.readthedocs.org/en/latest/validation.html#isvalidextension, you can put it to accept the answer

Comment: @user1655410 I've added details of `isValidExtension` to my answer. :-)